# With Visual Studio Remote Debugging, How can I figure out why my code works if I start it remotely, but it fails locally

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging

I added this revision to the question:
How might I debug this situation to figure out the problem?

I have a project that is set up to use Remote Debugging.
I configured it so I can start debugging remotely (instead of attaching to an already running program).
When I run it in the debugger, it works fine.  I am sure of this because it shows a progress bar that fills up for about a minute as it is running.
But if I run it from a CMD shell on the remote machine it fails instantly with a windows pop up saying that my program has stopped working.
What could be different that would make it work with a debugger and fail without.

Also note that I put a while loop with a sleep in it so that I could run it, attach to it, then change a value in the debugger to let it run past that.  BUT when I run it from the command line it exits before it hits that loop, so I cannot attach the debugger to it.

Comment: Use `DebugBreak()` instead of a `while()` loop.

Comment: Sadly I don't think DebugBreak() will work while remote debugging.  On the remote machine, when it fails it gives the option to debug, but it cannot.  I assume that the remote debug package doesn't support that scenario.

Comment: When you say " it cannot", what happens when you choose the Debug option?  Also, how close to the beginning of `main` did you place your loop?  It should be the first thing.  If it still doesn't get to the loop, then it would mean that it is something happening before `main` begins.  That could be any global objects you have declared becoming instantiated but failing instantiation, and/or the startup runtime is being executed and failing.

Comment: About "it cannot" If I choose to debug, it opens the choose a version of visual studio to debug with, and then if I choose that version I get an odd licensing message.  Note that Visual Studio is not installed on that remote machine.  But the Visual Studio thing that allows remote debugging is.

Comment: About where the loop is: it is the first set of statements in main.  The code is like:   int test = 5; while(test) { sleep(100); }  But it is multi-line so that I can put a break point in.  Also note that if I run it on the machine with Visual Studio, that it does hit that break point and I then can change the value of test to 0 and then it continues along and runs the code.   As a reminder the problem only happens on the remote machine.

Comment: Is this a C++ program?